# Ubuntu 20.04 screenshot trouble

Tags: 20.04, gnome-screenshot

ubuntu 20.04

my screenshot has a problem, it won't save in the clipboard and then paste, sometimes it still saves the previous screenshot or even doesn't do the latest screenshot? what should I check first?

what I've done

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-screenshot
```